# How to avoid duplication between constructors when they call different base constructors

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I have seen many variants of this question asked on SO, but the solutions don't apply in this case.

I have code similar to this, but with lengthy constructors in `Derived`, which I'd like to avoid duplicating.

```
abstract class Base
{
    private int ID;

    protected Base( int id )
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    protected Base()
    {
        ID = GenerateID();
    }

    private int GenerateID()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public readonly int SomeField;
    
    public Derived( int SomeFieldInitialValue ) : base()
    {
        SomeField = SomeFieldInitialValue;
    }

    public Derived( int SomeFieldInitialValue, int id ) : base( id )
    {
        // Want to remove this duplication - could be a long constructor.
        // Can't put it in a method because it does things that only constructors can do.
        SomeField = SomeFieldInitialValue;
    }
}
```

I can't create a helper method in `Derived` to contain the code common to all constructors, since some of that code can only be done in constructors (e.g. setting readonly members).

I can't use just one base constructor and pass along default values, as the value that would get used for `Base.ID` is known only to `Base` (computed in the private `GenerateID` method).

I can't use field initializers, as fields aren't initialised to the same thing in each constructor, and their values depend on constructor parameters.

I'd rather not expose `Base.GenerateID` to derived classes to pass along in the absence of an id to pass along, as there's no other reason to expose it, and it seems messy to push base functionality up into derived classes. Also there are likely to be other details in future beyond just an int - there's all sorts of other code that may or may not need to be run depending on which `Base` constructor is called - giving `Derived` knowledge of that seems bad.

I'd rather avoid removing the `readonly` from members of `Derived` as they're `readonly` on purpose.

I have a feeling that the answer is going to be "sorry, C# doesn't allow that" and I'll have to pick between one of the options I don't want to take :) I think the option that's least bad is to remove `readonly` or perhaps replace those fields with `private set` properties.

Comment: To add one option: define the base c'tor as `Base(int? id)`, calling GenerateId if the parameter is null. Also, define `private Derived(int SomeFieldInitialValue, int? id)` doing all the work and redirect from the public c'tors to this new one.

Comment: It's a bit too abstract question. Can you refactor base class to have just one constructor there? E.g. use factory method to create instance with generated id. Then you can chain derived class constructors by calling `this(...)` instead of `base(...)`, this will keep all initialization in one place.

Comment: Agree with Klaus - since Base constructors are all protected and class is abstract - combining them into one (accepting `int?`) won't hurt the "public" usage (won't make it less convenient), while fixing your problem with inherited classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the base class, it would be better to have only a single constructor there. This could then provide the two options (fixed ID or newly generated ID) like so:

```
abstract class Base
{
    private int ID;

    protected Base( int? id )
    {
        ID = id ?? GenerateID();
    }

    private int GenerateID()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Also in the derived class, define a (private or protected) constructor doing all the heavy work, and then public constructors redirecting to this.

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public readonly int SomeField;
    
    protected Derived( int SomeFieldInitialValue, int? id ) : base(id)
    {
        SomeField = SomeFieldInitialValue;
    }
    
    public Derived( int SomeFieldInitialValue ) : this( SomeFieldInitialValue, null)
    {
    }

    public Derived( int SomeFieldInitialValue, int id ) : this( SomeFieldInitialValue, id )
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh. I really like this. Thanks! I have the *slightest* worry about it being less efficient than calling different constructors directly (I work in game development so efficiency is a huge priority) but creating objects (and calling constructors) is already acknowledged to be slow, so making constructors slower shouldn't matter :)